# Is there a way to tell whether an email was forwarded in either the Case or EmailMessage Object?

Tags: email, email2case, status

I'm working on a particular project and need something to happen once an email in a case in Salesforce is forwarded. I tried to use 'Status' in the EmailMessage object and the related Case object, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forwarded how? In Salesforce? In an email client? Something else?

Comment: In Salesforce using the email options that appear in the thread when you have an email-to-case.